# Vertica Authentication Allow all IPv4

Tags: vertica

When I am creating AUTHENTICATION in vertica to allow users to connect from any IP its only allowing localhost connections.

```
CREATE AUTHENTICATION noIpRestictionNoTLS METHOD 'hash' HOST NO TLS '0.0.0.0/0';
```

Below is the document provided by Vertica which states to allow users to connect from any ipv4 address.

[image: Documentation from vertica]

Please let me know what command we can use to create authentication to allow from any IP .

Answer (score 0):

[image: Follow below Flow Diagram to Handle Authentication]

Authentication Diagram With Roles